# Word for describing when you're doing a price quotation

Tags: word-choice

Yes, the system does literally a "price quotation", but "quotation", without "price" means something like "quoting" (as you see the quote, please) when it is individually used, I mean, also when it is pluralized it sounds like I'm quoting a lot of phrases of famous people.

Well, is there something more specific for this sort of stuff? I mean, the proposal of the system is of choosing the cheapest bids for the products that I want buy, so, basically, **dealers** put their price for a respective product and we always choose who has the cheapest bid for that product.

Comment: I've never expected Shakespeare or Groucho when a workman has asked if I'd like a quote.

Comment: But you read on books about his quotes, as you search in the same way for them. http://i.imgur.com/XLRNHZf.png, http://i.imgur.com/ZSmsJGw.png

Comment: If you look up almost any word in say AHDEL, you'll find numerous different senses listed. We get by. Just think if you had to learn say 50 different words for 'set'.

Comment: Well, makes sense. So do you agree about `quotation` in this context?

Comment: You could look this up yourself. Google's dictionary has: quotation noun
1.
a group of words taken from a text or speech and repeated by someone other than the original author or speaker.
"a quotation from Mark Twain"
...

2.
a formal statement setting out the estimated cost for a particular job or service.
"ensure you receive a written quotation covering all aspects of the job"

Comment: Workmen commonly use "quote" as a noun meaning quotation. Hostesses not schooled in etiquette use "invite" as a noun meaning "invitation". These are examples of "nouning"; i.e., using the related verb as a noun, when there is already a perfectly good noun, but the verb is shorter, so it's easier/quicker to say. The reverse also happens (turning a noun into a verb); "impact", for example. This is called "verbing". Both of these are jarring to us conventionalists, but language marches on.

Answer (score 1):

[Pricing:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pricing)is a common alternative to 'quotation'

> - the evaluation of something in terms of its price
> - the amount as of money or goods, asked for or given in exchange for something else.